# Excel: Running occurrence of items in table column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-tables

I am trying to achieve this in a table in Excel:
https://exceljet.net/formula/running-count-of-occurrence-in-list

So, counting each item in the list in an ordered sequence:

[image]

(I want it for Red and Green too, of course)

If I however convert it to a table, and add something like these variants, then I get a total instead for each. Is there a way to achieve this in a table column? The only other answer I found to this was within Power Query, which I won't be using for this table:

```
=IF([@Color]="blue",COUNTIF([Color]:[@Color],"blue"),"")
=IF([@Color]=[@Color],COUNTIF([Color]:[@Color],[@Color]),"")
=IF([@Color]="blue",COUNTIF([@Color],"blue"),"")
=IF([@Color]=[@Color],COUNTIF([@Color],[@Color]),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INDEX()` to refer to the range at hand per row:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUM(--(INDEX([Color],1):[@Color]=[@Color]))
```

Meaning:

- `INDEX([Color],1)` - Always refer to the first row in the "Color" column;
- `:` - Continue creating a valid range reference;
- `[@Color]` - Refer to the current row/value.
- `=[@Color]` - Match the above structure against the current row/value.
- `--` - Turn the `TRUE/FALSE` array into `1/0` values.
- `SUM()` - Sum the given array to a total.

Note, the website you have tagged is quite handy, they also have exactly what you are after covered on another page. See [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/running-count-in-table).

Also, I guess this needs to be **CSE-entered** in pre-365 versions of Excel.

Comment: Great! I was looking for a way to formulate mixed references for table columns, but could not find it at all. Only regular ranges like $A$1:A1 for example. This does it. Thanks!